# Append second dataset to existing chartjs chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is there a way to add a second a second dataset to an existing chartjs chart?
I've got a pre-rendered chart on my website and like to add a second dataset to the chart on a button click.

I've got a function that creates me a bar chart with one dataset item

```
function renderChart(dataset_energy){
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
      var data = {
            labels:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Mai"],
            datasets: [
            {
                 label: "My First dataset",
                 fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                 strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                 highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                 highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                 data: data //data = [523,523,356,31,234]
               },
            ]
       };
     myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
}
```

My challenge is now, how to add a second dataset with the same labels to the existing chart. Unfortunately there isn't any `appendDataset`-function in the library

Als solution I tried the following approach:
I create a dummy canvas, extract the new created dataset, push it o the real canvas and update my chart. Unfortunately, everything is rerendered, but the chart didn't appear. Also the mouse-over shows that there is a second dataset!

Detailed code onI jsfiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ms1zrs7j/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solve the issue: Solution was provided by this [Diskussion](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/813)

I use the `.destroy()`-method and draw a new chart.